# Gurobi cannot solve LP after Update -> Status Code 1

Tags: c++, gurobi

After I updated my Gurobi, I cannot solve my LP anymore. I tried to debug, but come not further than

```
GRBEnv env = GRBEnv();
```

Trying to continue, it fails with Signal= SIGABRT. I am not sure if this has anything to do with my update of gurobi, since the general gurobi example still works fine (http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/6.0/quickstart_mac/cpp_interface.html). Moreover, when I let it run instead of debugging, I get the following output:

```
Solved in 0 iterations and 0.00 seconds
Optimal objective  0.000000000e+00
obj: 0
Status1
```

I know that Status 1 means that the problem is only loaded, but not solved (I have written model.optimize at the end). The LP Code is quite long and I am not sure where to look for the mistake. So any hint would be useful. Btw, I am using gurobi in c++ on a mac.

Comment: As as aside, why aren't you just writing `GRBEnv env;`?

Comment: I am new to Gurobi and C++, so that is how I found it in some tutorials. Is there a big difference? I tried it out, but it did not solve my problem.

Comment: I didn't say it would solve your problem, but the tutorials you have been reading are wrong. Learn C++ from a _book_!